# How do I feed real-time data from matlab (.m) file to simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have an AD converted signal from an input that is stored in a fixed size buffer. Every iteration of my read process, the data is sent to a function (let's call it function.m).

My main file (main.m, let's say) reads a some samples and stores in a variable. It then calls for function.m where I do some processing. Inside function.m, I want to have it call a simulink block that I am designing and have the return value of function.m to be the result of the processing made in this simulink block.

For a more visual approach:

- main.m

  ```
  ARec = dsp.AudioRecorder('SampleRate',Fs, ...
  'NumChannels',CH_AD, ...
  'BufferSizeSource','Property',...
  'BufferSize',Buffer, ...
  'QueueDuration',QueueDuration, ... // tamanho pode ser variavel
  'SamplesPerFrame', Buffer);

  while(1),
   yh1 = step(ARec);
   [yh3] = function_PhaseShifter(yh1);
   step(APly, yh3);
  end;
  ```
- function_PhaseShifter

  ```
  function [y]=function_PhaseShifter(x)
      %Here do some simulink work
      %where X is the input to simulink block
      %y is assigned from simulink block's result
  end
  ```

Comment: Within `function_PhaseShifter` you need to use the [sim](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/sim.html) function to call you model.  However, you need to remember that neither MATLAB or Simulink are real-time environments, so depending on the sample rates your whole approach may not be viable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. We have tested and the whole solution has ~50ms delay, which is enough for what we are doing. Thanks!